# Finding coefficient of generating function 1

Tags: generating-functions

I was solving some problem related to generating functions ,and I have to find it's coefficient : So after some steps , I reached to this :
$ ( 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5) ( 1 + x + x^2) $ 
By Generating functions , $( ( 1 -x^5 /1 - x)$ *  $ ( 1 -x^6/1 - x)$ * $ ( 1 -x^3/1 - x))$ ,
 $( 1 -x^5 )( 1 -x^6)(1 -x^3 )/(1 - x)^3$ ,
Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Which term do you have to find the coefficient of?

Comment: @B.Mehta  , I had to find no. of ways to select 1 to 10 cars , from a pile of 4 Skoda , 5 Toyata and 2 Mercedes .

Comment: If you really have to find all the coefficients of $x^1$, $x^2$, ... $x^{10}$ then you might as well just multiply the original three polynomials. Just long-multiply $111111$ by $11111$ and then by $111$ BUT DON'T CARRY, do it in base $79$ or whatever.

Comment: Suggestion: Expand $(1-x^5)(1-x^6)(1-x^3)$ by simple multiplication, and write $(1-x)^{-3}$ as an infinite series by the binomial theorem.